# Sitecore Refresh Index

Tags: indexing, sitecore, sitecore7, sitecore7.2

I am working on Sitecore 7.2 and using Lucene search, I have created few templates and pages and search is working fine, now I want to exclude few templates from the index, I have a custom crawler and that does remove the templates from indexes but  index is not refreshed, I am using following code to update index

```cs
foreach (Cache cache in CacheManager.GetAllCaches())
{
    //WriteLog(string.Concat(" Clearing Cache, name = ", cache.Name));
    cache.Clear();
}
//WriteLog("Clearing caching finished");
var index = ContentSearchManager.GetIndex("sitecore_global_index");
index.RebuildAsync(IndexingOptions.ForcedIndexing, new System.Threading.CancellationToken(false));
index.Reset();
//index.Refresh();
```

Comment: Have you tried to rebuild it manually from Sitecore Desktop?

Comment: Yes, it works from desktop but I want to do in code.

Answer (score 1):

The following code worked for me before, It will index the content tree starting from RootItemInTree and below:

```cs
index.Refresh(new SitecoreIndexableItem(RootItemInTree));
```

Comment: I have used this method but there is some magic happens when I index from the control panel. I am also using Index Viewer to view items in the index and it shows new items when I index from control panel. I imagine there is an indexing job that runs when indexing is performed through control panel but I am unable to find that job. Do you have any idea of indexing job?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to rebuild index programmatically is:

```
Sitecore.ContentSearch.ContentSearchManager.GetIndex("Your_Index_Name").Rebuild();
```

This GetIndex() method has been refactored into ContentSearchManager, previously it was kept in this class:

```
Sitecore.Search.SearchManager
```

..for some people it has made issues, so good to keep in mind.

In case you want to find out index name(s) programmatically (let's say you'd like to iterate through them), retrieve them from:

```
ContentSearchManager.Indexes
```

Hope this helps, please let us know if you got further questions.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Since you are trying to use Asynchronous method, you are using it incorrectly. Use "await" prefix.

```
**await** index.RebuildAsync(IndexingOptions.ForcedIndexing, new System.Threading.CancellationToken(false));
```

It is working for me.

```
protected async void RebuildIndexAsync()
{
 foreach (Cache cache in CacheManager.GetAllCaches())
 {
    //WriteLog(string.Concat(" Clearing Cache, name = ", cache.Name));
    cache.Clear();
 }
 //WriteLog("Clearing caching finished");
 var index = ContentSearchManager.GetIndex("sitecore_global_index");
 await index.RebuildAsync(IndexingOptions.ForcedIndexing, new    System.Threading.CancellationToken(false));
 index.Reset();
 //index.Refresh();
}
```