# Sitecore - delete bucket subitems

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7

I have items importer which deletes all item subitems and creates new subitems. Recently I switched it to buckets and now I have a problem with deleting.
I delete items using:

```
myItem.DeleteChildren();
```

Without bucket it took about 20min. Now it takes about 1h for 5k items. Do I need to revert bucket item before deleting and then synchronize again?
What is the quickest way to delete bucketable items?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take it a step further. I was able to import 30k in minutes by disabling all three.

```
using (new Sitecore.SecurityModel.SecurityDisabler())
{
    using (new Sitecore.Data.Events.EventDisabler())
    {
        using (new ProxyDisabler())
        {
            //delete code here
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When I am adding bucket subitem, do I have to use something different than myBucket.Add() method like usual? I have added some items and I can's find them in Sitecore Content Editor

Comment: Just add items like normal and they will be put into a bucket. If they are not going into the bucket automatically, then your template is not set to "bucket" in the standard values.

Answer (score 2):

My guess is, your deletion takes longer now because the bucket is updating indexes while deleting. While you could speed it up by disabling events around your .DeleteChildren call, you would still need to get those indexes updated for your bucket to function properly.

So to answer your question, there isn't a way to speed it up while still retaining full functionality.

If you want to test this in action, try the following:

```
using(new EventDisabler()) myItem.DeleteChildren();
```

It should bring the deletion speed up to where it was before, but at the price of a bucket that will not work properly, until indexes have been built.

I would recommend you adapt an integration approach, where complete deletion and rebuilding of your item store is not required.

Comment: Yes. But it should also catch up on it's own. Eventually. Just be aware; that from the time you did the import, and the time the index updates, anything you query via the bucket API will give inconsistent/wrong results.

For index rebuilding: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31419638/sitecore-refresh-index

Answer (score 1):

If you have a lot of items in the bucket, it will execute events on each item that is being deleted. Put your delete code inside an event disabler:

```
using (new EventDisabler())
{
   myItem.DeleteChildren();
}
```

That will stop all the events from firing and should be considerably quicker. As a caveat - the indexes will not be updated instantly when doing this, so you might want to run a index update on the master DB after your importer has run.

Another option would be to update existing items in the import rather than deleting all the items first.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe (programatically) unbucket before calling DeleteChildren() ? I don't know how long that will take in total but might be quicker than it is now